# What is the meaning of "dollars per module"?

Tags: pmp

I am working through Rita (8th edition) and there was the following question:

*Which of the following is an example of parametric estimates?*

The correct answer is *Dollars per module*. Of course I was able to exclude the other possibilities, however I don't know what's the meaning of *Dollars per module*.

Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind a parametric estimate is that you establish the measurement you are interested in against a unit that is meaningful to you.  They are using the term module to represent a unit in generic terms.  The unit could be square feet or square yards, produce release, gallons, or something like that.  You are essentially creating a ratio in the most simplest terms so that you can compare equally one effort to the next.  For example, burning 300 gallons of fuel to get from point A to B and comparing that to burning 500 gallons to get from point C to D is not meaningful.  However, if you break it down to miles / gallon, then you can compare the two different driving efforts.

Here's an example:

Apartment A rents for $600.  Apartment B rents for $800.  You are trying to establish a rent price for Apartment C.  They are all in the same geographic area.  How do you do this?

In this industry, they establish the parametric of dollars / square foot.

If Apartment A is 1,000 sq. ft. and B is 1,300 sq. ft. and C is 2,000 sq. ft., what would you charge for apartment C?

Maybe $1,200 assuming all else is equal??

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I translate the word `module`, I can't get a suitable meaning ;-).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Module means a program module , its a part of program , so this means how many dollars you will pay for on module the answer is A